# Problem With SimpleXML Parsing WoWArmory attributes

Tags: php, simplexml

This is an example item:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [displayInfoId] => 62116
            [durability] => 100
            [gem0Id] => 41401
            [gem1Id] => 40123
            [gem2Id] => 0
            [gemIcon0] => inv_jewelcrafting_shadowspirit_02
            [gemIcon1] => inv_jewelcrafting_gem_37
            [icon] => inv_helmet_98
            [id] => 48592
            [level] => 245
            [maxDurability] => 100
            [name] => Liadrin's Headpiece of Triumph
            [permanentEnchantIcon] => ability_warrior_shieldmastery
            [permanentEnchantItemId] => 44876
            [permanentenchant] => 3819
            [pickUp] => PickUpLargeChain
            [putDown] => PutDownLArgeChain
            [randomPropertiesId] => 0
            [rarity] => 4
            [seed] => 0
            [slot] => 0
        )

)
```

I'm trying to get a JSON object with each item, but there's about 17 or something, and if I try to `json_encode()` it's giving me "@attributes" as an object containing all the stuff I want. Help?

Comment: sorry I am a bit confused, if this is php code, there where are the commas to separate the key-value pairs? and the terminator semi-colon? where did you get this?

Comment: @Michael Looks like a `print_r` of the SimpleXML object

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get an JSON Object from a SimpleXML Object.

Comment: I did a quick test of passing SimpleXMLElement to `json_encode()` and I see *""@attributes" as an object containing all the stuff"* as you said. Where is the problem?  Here's what I get: `{"@attributes":{"a":"1","b":"2"}}` Do you want to get rid of the outer object?

Comment: Yeah, I want to get rid of the @attributes. Looking at Phil's answer, it might work, trying it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
$jsonArray = array();
foreach ($xmlObj->attributes() as $attr => $value) {
    $jsonArray[$attr] = (string)$value;
}

$jsonString = json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Edit: You may also be able to simply use

```
$jsonString = json_encode($xmlObj->attributes());
```

however I'm not sure if the attribute values are returned as strings or objects (edit - turns out you can't. See Artefacto's solution).

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$sxm = new SimpleXMLElement("<a name=\"kkk\" other=\"foo\"/>");
$attrs = $sxm->attributes();
var_dump(json_encode(reset($attrs)));
```

gives:

```
string(28) "{"name":"kkk","other":"foo"}"
```

The problem you were experiencing was because `$xmlObj->attributes()` returns a `SimpleXMLElement` that, when converted as an array, is an array with the key "@attributes" and a value with an array that actually has the attributes as (name => value) pairs.

Comment: +1 But the `attributes()` call is not needed. You can your use `reset()` on the element directly. That said it may be *safer* to use it to ensure that the attributes are the first element in the array.

Comment: `reset` won't work on object (which is what `$sxm` is or `$sxm->attributes()` returns). You have to cast it to an array first. I believe this is a behavior that changed in 5.3.

Comment: @netcoder `reset` works on traversable objects, which SimpleXMLElement is.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$array = (array)$simplexml->node->attributes();
$jsonArray = json_encode($array['@attributes']);
```